# Generate a unique access key for account setup with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique-key

I'm trying to come up with an efficient way to generate/validate unique access keys for an application I'm writing. The issue I'm having is because of how the SQL database is set up.

Basically, there are two tables in question. A `Users` table and a `Faculty` table. There is a one to many relationship between the `Users` and `Faculty` tables. Every user will create an account using just a **personal** email and password. That will create an entry in the `Users` table.

Now, I want to allow admins to enter a **domain** email and name, and generate a setup key. The user will then be able to enter that access key which will link their row in the `Users` table to a row in the `Faculty` table with a `user_id` foreign key.

The way I've thought about doing it is that when an admin generates the setup key it will create a row in the faculty table with a null foreign key. The user would then have to enter the setup key **AND** the **domain** email that the admin entered. Assuming it all matched, it would then add their `user_id` to that foreign key column.

Here's where the issues/questions lie. Would it be more efficient to use a separate table containing the setup keys and emails as sort of a lookup table and only searching a table with two columns before adding a row to the `faculty` table? I think this may be faster as rows could be deleted once they were validated leaving fewer rows to search every time. Also, I'm not sure if there is an issue with leaving the foreign key null as in my first method.

Assuming a unique key/email pair, would that be secure enough, or would I also need some way to check against the signed in user?

Any resources or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there would be large benefit in performance if you create a separate table for this purpose, but it would have a large benefit on data integrity. Creating a new faculty record for every allowed access would cause redundancy, since you will have to add the same faculty in multiple records and would create large problems on the long-run, being ever more difficult to handle all the redundancies, ultimately leading to inconsistencies. So, the initial approach would violate the concept of [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). You will have much better results if you have a table for users, a table for faculties and another table for users_of_faculties. This would allow users to have access to more faculties if that's needed and each user, each faculty would be created at exactly one place, their relation would be more frequently changed, when access is granted, modified or revoked for some users at some faculties.

Comment: I guess I should have gave more information. There are also Schools and each School can have many faculty. A Faculty can also be a part of multiple Schools. That is why I was thinking a user may have multiple rows in the faculty table.

Comment: @Kenta I think that the 1:n relation between schools and their faculties doesn't change the fact that the faculty is conceptually different from user. So, even though your project is more complex than it appeared to be for me at my initial glance, my opinion didn't change: I believe that you need to prevent redundancies by having a user table, a faculty table and a user_of_faculty table. The access of a user to a faculty seems to be a concept on its own. Or, to put it differently: user access doesn't seem to be an attribute of a faculty.